# Get value of child array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get current USD/EUR rate using this api link:

http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR

Using this code:

```
$url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price = $json->rates[0]->EUR;
```

I want result of `$price` to be like: `"0.84782"`,
but it seems I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't help anyone. Show what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: I'm excepting $price to be 0.84782 and in fact it doesnt display anything.

Comment: What is the content of `$json`? Did you even attempt to debug your code? I mean it's 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=EUR";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price=$json['rates']['EUR'];
echo $price;
```

This will work for you. The price you are looking for is a nested array so you must first access the parent one.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `true` to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), so the returned value is an array. To use object instead, remove `true`, like so:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Access it like this:

```
echo $json->rates->EUR; // Output is: 0.84782
```

---

If you want to access array style:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $json['rates']['EUR']; // 0.84782
```

Comment: @axel.miche thank you. I copied the wrong line from my local test lul